# Return/obtain values from json if keypair matches - Python

Tags: python, json, for-loop, parsing

Currently I am able to pull a list of hard drive statuses from a website using its api. **I want to slim down my results and have return back the data that the key pair "status": "Degraded", or "status": "Pred Fail" from my result.**

Here is what the json looks like without any parsing:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "bytesPerSector": 512,
      "description": "SSD",
      "interfaceType": "RAID",
      "manufacturer": "UNKNOWN",
      "mediaType": "Fixed hard disk media",
      "model": "OEM Genuine 500GB",
      "name": "\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0",
      "partitionCount": 1,
      "serialNumber": "Notputting that in here",
      "size": 500105249280,
      "smartCapable": true,
      "status": "OK",
      "deviceId": taking this out as well,
      "timestamp": 1573080987.0
    },
```

Currently, I have slimmed down my results to only show ['interfaceType'],['manufacturer'],['model'],['status']; however, I only want to pull the sections that have ['status':'Degraded'] or ['status':'Pred Fail'] as their status for the hard drive. (If that make sense?)

Here is the code I have so far:

```py
alerts = ''
for i in range (len(napialert['results'])):
    ninjainterfaceType_str = json.dumps(napialert['results'][i]['interfaceType'], indent=2,)
    ninjamanufacturer_str = json.dumps(napialert['results'][i]['manufacturer'], indent=2,)
    ninjamodel = json.dumps(napialert['results'][i]['model'], indent=2,)
    ninjastatus = json.dumps(napialert['results'][i]['status'], indent=2,)
    alerts += (ninjainterfaceType_str + "\n" + ninjamanufacturer_str + "\n" + ninjamodel + "\n" + ninjastatus + "\n _____________________________\n")
    
print("Here are a list of Hard drive with manufacturer problems: " + alerts)
```

Here are the results (but it prints all of them instead of just the ones that have a failure status):

```
Here are a list of Hard drive with manufacturer problems: "RAID"
"UNKNOWN"
"OEM Genuine 500GB"
"OK"
 _____________________________
"SATA"
"Western Digital"
"WDC WD1502FAEX-007BA0"
"OK"
 _____________________________
"SATA"
"UNKNOWN"
"ADATA SP550"
"OK"

More below this...
```

Let me know if anyone has any ideas or suggestions to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing nothing to actually examine the status...?

Your `for` loop is also weird; since you don't care how many items there are or the index of the current one within the list, just loop over the items themselves, instead of the range of list indices.

```py
for res in napialert['results']:
    if res['status'] in ('Degraded', 'Pred Fail'):
        for attr in ('interfaceType', 'manufacturer', 'model', 'status'):
            print(res[attr])
```

I could also see no reason to collect the strings into a list and only print when we have basically doubled (no, wait, tripled) the program's memory consumption. Just print as soon as you find a match, and move on to the next one. The weird dance to convert each individual string back to JSON (i.e. effectively add double quotes around it) also seemed superfluous, but will of course be easy to put back in if it actually adds value.

Comment: This completely worked for me! I am putting your answer as the right answer because its more efficient. I am just learning python so my technique is terrible as far as efficiency but the reason I put it into a string is because I am going to be using tkinter to make the app graphical. so I have some `"n\" + "__________" + "n\"` to make it look better in tkinter. There may be a better method than this but I will be looking into that soon. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of potential issues, the first one might be with the format of the json object you are getting it has '"' that might need to get stripped, maybe your API is actually returning this correctly, if that's the case is just matter of doing an actual check on the status property, you can find an example below, using an array and checking if the status of the current object is in that array:

```
import json

napialert = {
  "results": [
    {
      "bytesPerSector": 512,
      "description": "SSD",
      "interfaceType": "RAID",
      "manufacturer": "UNKNOWN",
      "mediaType": "Fixed hard disk media",
      "model": "OEM Genuine 500GB",
      "name": "\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0",
      "partitionCount": 1,
      "serialNumber": "Notputting that in here",
      "size": 500105249280,
      "smartCapable": True,
      "status": "OK",
      "deviceId": "taking this out as well",
      "timestamp": 1573080987.0
    },
        {
      "bytesPerSector": 512,
      "description": "SSD",
      "interfaceType": "RAID",
      "manufacturer": "UNKNOWN",
      "mediaType": "Fixed hard disk media",
      "model": "OEM Genuine 500GB",
      "name": "\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0",
      "partitionCount": 1,
      "serialNumber": "Notputting that in here",
      "size": 500105249280,
      "smartCapable": True,
      "status": "Degraded",
      "deviceId": "taking this out as well",
      "timestamp": 1573080987.0
    },
        {
      "bytesPerSector": 512,
      "description": "SSD",
      "interfaceType": "RAID",
      "manufacturer": "UNKNOWN",
      "mediaType": "Fixed hard disk media",
      "model": "OEM Genuine 500GB",
      "name": "\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0",
      "partitionCount": 1,
      "serialNumber": "Notputting that in here",
      "size": 500105249280,
      "smartCapable": True,
      "status": "Pred Fail",
      "deviceId": "taking this out as well",
      "timestamp": 1573080987.0
    }
    ]
}

alerts = ''
checks = ["Pred Fail", "Degraded"]
for i in range (len(napialert['results'])):
    status = json.dumps(napialert['results'][i]['status'])
    if status.strip('"') in checks:
        ninjainterfaceType_str = json.dumps(napialert['results'][i]['interfaceType'], indent=2,)
        ninjamanufacturer_str = json.dumps(napialert['results'][i]['manufacturer'], indent=2,)
        ninjamodel = json.dumps(napialert['results'][i]['model'], indent=2,)
        ninjastatus = json.dumps(napialert['results'][i]['status'], indent=2,)
        alerts += (ninjainterfaceType_str + "\n" + ninjamanufacturer_str + "\n" + ninjamodel + "\n" + ninjastatus + "\n _____________________________\n")
    
print("Here are a list of Hard drive with manufacturer problems: " + alerts)
```